# How to fix 'jsx' must be in scope in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-context

I am using React 17.

I have a [React Context](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) provider component:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const MyContext = createContext({} as MyContextType);

export const MyContextProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ isReady }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

On `<MyContext.Provider />` ESlint is complaining about:

> 'jsx' must be in scope when using JSXeslintreact/react-in-jsx-scope

In my `eslintrc.js` I added: `'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',` then the red line in VSCode is gone but when I try to compile my React app, I get this error: `jsx is not defined`

How to fix this issue?

**Update:**

When I change the `JSX Pragma` from [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma) into `import React from 'react'` it works. Why is that?

Comment: what component do you wrap in MyContextProvider

Comment: If you're using babel check https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-preset-react and https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

Answer (score 0):

the [`@jsx` pragma](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx#pragma) tells [jsx babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) which function must be used to compile JSX expressions and it's `React.createElement` by default, you may change it when working with [emotion's `css` Prop](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma) for example:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'

...

  <p
    css={{
      color: 'blue',
    ...
```

So you have to import the `jsx` from the corresponding package or delete the line to use `React.createElement` (the default one)